# Ranking extra criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ranking

I came across this formula yesterday and wondered if someone would be able to help expand it for me. This is what I found below:

```
=COUNTIF($C$1:$C$99,">"&C1)+1+SUMPRODUCT(--($C$1:$C$99=C1),--($B$1:$B$99>B1))
```

This formula is for 2 sets of criteria, in column C and then B.

Can anyone please help me add a third set of criteria, which would be in column D?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use COUNTIFS in the original formula unless you have a very old version of Excel

```
=COUNTIF($C$1:$C$10,">"&C1)+1+COUNTIFS($C$1:$C$10,C1,$B$1:$B$10,">"&B1)
```

Then just add another column in the same way (I have used column A because it was testing column C first and moving right to left)

```
=COUNTIF($C$1:$C$10,">"&C1)+1+COUNTIFS($C$1:$C$10,C1,$B$1:$B$10,">"&B1)+COUNTIFS($C$1:$C$10,C1,$B$1:$B$10,B1,$A$1:$A$10,">"&A1)
```

Plz change ranges as required.

[image]

Comment: Tom, thank you so much. You are an absolute life saver.

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful.